# How to reset page after "Resize Page to Selection" in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I used "Resize Page to Selection" in Inkscape, but now want to reset my page dimensions and position to where it was originally. I can select A4 again, which gives me the right size, but page is now in the wrong position. The top-left is where the original select was made, and the page extends from there.

How do I reset the page back to its original configuration?

Answer (score 1):

When resizing to content, Inkscape usually offsets all layers by setting `transform`-attributes on them. You can try going through all the outer-most `<svg:g>`-tags in the 'Edit → XML-Editor...' and deleting the `transform` by clicking on the remove icon next to it. This won't work if these already had other transform values before the resize, though, since they will revert to an even earlier state then.

[image: XML-Editor deleting transform example]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but a way to avoid the problem entirely. Inkscape 1.2 now has multi-page support, so there is no need to alter your original page/layout. Do the following instead:

1. Create a new page using the Create and Edit Document Pages tool [image]
2. Select and Duplicate the graphic <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
3. Move the duplicated graphic onto the new page, making sure the graphic is selected
4. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to resize the new page to the selection.

This will affect only the duplicate graphic on the new page, leaving the layout of your original page unaffected.

For example

[image]